# Can we write a Hashtable to a file?

Tags: java, hashtable

I have a `Hashtable<string,string>`, in my program I want to record the values of the Hashtable to process later.

My question is: can we write object Hastable to a file?  If so, how can we later load that file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, using binary serialization ([`ObjectOutputStream`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html)):

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("t.tmp");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

oos.writeObject(yourHashTable);
oos.close();
```

Then you can read it using `ObjectInputStream`

The objects that you put inside the `Hashtable` (or better - `HashMap`) have to implement `Serializable`

---

If you want to store the `Hashtable` in a human-readable format, you can use `java.beans.XMLEncoder`:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("tmp.xml");
XMLEncoder e = new XMLEncoder(fos);
e.writeObject(yourHashTable);
e.close();
```

Comment: Thanks your reply !

I have question 

my hastable <string url,string urlcontent>
how can i write in file xml like 
<url1>
<contenturl1>
////
</contenturl1>
</url1>
<url2>
<contenturl2>
////
</contenturl2>
<url2>

Comment: You can use something like XStream or JAXB to customize the xml, but it is too much headache. I'd stick with XMLEncoder, or with the proposed `Properties` solution.

Answer (score 5):

Don't know about your specific application, but you might want to have a look at the [Properties class](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html). (It extends hashmap.)

This class provides you with

> ```
> void  load(InputStream inStream)
>      Reads a property list (key and element pairs) from the input byte stream.
> void  load(Reader reader)
>      Reads a property list (key and element pairs) from the input character stream in a simple line-oriented format.
> void  loadFromXML(InputStream in)
>      Loads all of the properties represented by the XML document on the specified input stream into this properties table.
> void  store(Writer writer, String comments)
>       Writes this property list (key and element pairs) in this Properties table to the output character stream in a format suitable for using the load(Reader) method.
> void  storeToXML(OutputStream os, String comment)
>       Emits an XML document representing all of the properties contained in this table.
> ```

[The tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html) is quite educational also.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to easily edit the map once it's written out, you might want to take a look at [jYaml](http://jyaml.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html). It allows you to easily write the map to a Yaml-formatted file, meaning it's easy to read and edit.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use **[MapDB](http://www.mapdb.org)** and it will save the HashMap for you after you do a `put` and a `commit`.
That way if the program crashes the values will still be persisted.