# How to write data structure to file for later use?

Tags: c

If I want to deal with some gigantic data, for example, search to find if one item in it, maybe I should sort these data first then a binary search. But the next time if I want to do the same job, I'd sort it again, for gigantic data, it's a pain, so maybe I should sort and store them somewhere for later use.

C provides some library tools to read/write, I can use them to operate into/out a array, but if I want to store some other valuable data structure such as a struct, a linked-list or even a hash table(again, with gigantic data in it) or Red-Black tree, how can I write these well constructed data in to a file and read them in to my program later ?

Here has a [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808277/can-we-write-a-hashtable-to-a-file) to deal with this problem in **Java**, and I want to know the answer in **C**.

Comment: Do a google search for serialization libraries.

Comment: I would be looking for a database, right now. Gigantic data = Database

Answer (score 1):

i think you can just use `fwrite` and `fread`, and open file with binary mode. example as below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return *(int *)a - *(int *)b;
}

int main()
{
    FILE *fin, *fout;
    int a[] = {1, 3, -1, 4, 19, 21, 17, 2, 10};
    int i, n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a);
    int *b = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    qsort(a, n, sizeof(int), cmp);

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%3d", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    fout = fopen("data.dat", "wb");
    fwrite(a, sizeof(a), n, fout);
    fclose(fout);

    fin = fopen("data.dat", "rb");
    fread(b, sizeof(int), n, fin);
    fclose(fin);

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%3d", b[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    free(b);
    return 0;
}

//  -1  1  2  3  4 10 17 19 21
//  -1  1  2  3  4 10 17 19 21
```