# Whats the best way to save a Hashtable to a file?

Tags: java

So I wrote a code that stores reminders. I used a `Hashtable` to store the reminders.
The key of the `Hashtable` is a Date object and the value is a `String` which represents the reminder content.
It's all working great. 
I need to save the `Hashtable` to a file(file name should be provided by the user). Also, I need to let the user to choose either to load the reminders from an existing file or make a new `Hashtable` of reminders and save it in the end in another file. What's the best way to do that?

Comment: I guess serialization would do the job

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we write a Hashtable to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808277/can-we-write-a-hashtable-to-a-file)

Comment: "The best way" is for you to decide. Should it be a binary file (serialized objects) or a text file? If text file, what format would you like? Properties file? CSV file? XML file? JSON file? Something else? Question is primarily opinion-based (what is "best") and/or too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the types of objects used for keys and values implement "[`Serializable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)" interface, you can [serialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447898/what-is-object-serialization) the HashTable.

E.g. if your hashtable is `Hashtable<KeyType, ValueType>`; both KeyType **and** ValueType must implement Serializable

Here's a good tutorial on serialization in Java: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

Please note that you can write your own custom serialization and deserialization methods, to convert to any format you want; if Java's default one somehow isn't OK for you.

Comment: Which class should implement Serializable? The one with the Hashtable?

Comment: @Losnikov - Hashtable itself already does. But HashTable maps one class (the key) to another (value) - both of THOSE, have to be Serializable too. E.g. if your values are random class you wrote; they won't be Serializable; if they are a String, they would be.

Comment: I mean, which class' signature in the package should be public class <class name> implements Serializable?

Comment: @Losnikov Since you said `Hashtable<Date, String>`, all 3 are already serializable. --- I would however suggest using a text file instead, i.e. format the dates as strings, create a `Properties` object with the mappings and save that.